# Android studio tells me I need a version of Gradle >= 1.8 and <=1.6

Tags: android, gradle, ros

Steps I took to download Android Studio: http://wiki.ros.org/sig/Rosjava/Android%20Studio/Download

So when I try to use the default gradle wrapper it tells me that I need to version 1.8. So I looked up how to fix this, and so I downloaded a gradle version 1.8. Whenever I use that, it tells me that I need version 1.6.

If it matters, I'm trying to use Android and ROS (so I'm trying to import android_apps programs into Android studio).

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

In a recent update of Android Studio, the android plugin for gradle was updated, and now requires Gradle 1.8.

Android Studio projects use a Gradle wrapper - its contained in every project. This takes care of the gradle stuff for you normally - i.e. you don't need to have Gradle installed on your system.

But because of this update you need to tell the wrapper the correct gradle version to use (because when the wrapper was created, it's gradle version was set up to 1.6, the old min gradle version).

**In your project directory, open gradle-wrapper.properties under gradle/wrapper/.**

Change the **distributionUrl** to:
**distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-all.zip**

Then in Android Studio, resync your gradle file, under the Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with gradle files.

Then rebuild your project (Build -> Rebuild Project).

Comment: yeah, this didn't work. I still get Gradle version 1.6 is required.